# Docker Restart Policy for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

is a good idea to set "restart: always" in a PostgresSQL container? Perhaps to use "restart: unless-stopped" is a better idea to prevent outdated containers?

Answer (score 1):

If with *"outdated containers"* you mean *"containers created from old images"* you don't have to worry because in both cases if you modify your `docker-compose.yml` with a new version of postgres and perform a `docker-compose up -d` you will get new container running.

The difference on the behavior is what happens if you stop a container and then the machine restarts (for any reason). If you have `restart: always` the container will be restarted, if you used `restart: unless-stopped` it will not spin-up.

Comment: Thank you. What's better for PostgreSQL in a production environment?

Comment: That's really depends on which behavior you would like to have. Personally i prefer `unless-stopped` while in development (so i don't have tons of containers spinning up if i reboot my machine) and `always` in production, since services will never be stopped, and is shorter to type :).